# Cisco ASA as ISP GW in small office

Tags: cisco-asa, isp

I have Cisco ASA forming static route relationship with a ISP router.

I'm not looking to use any fancy Anyconnect VPN or IPS Firewall.

But some simple ACLs to secure the network as security tone.

Config is pasted below,

Is stateful-firewall assumed in this case? Since only internally initiated traffic gets NAT-ed and returned from outside?

Does this config encompass the basic things required in security? (Block management access from outside, block ping, from outside, block private IP from outside, etc).

I'm having firewall/anti-virus hardening at individual host level.
Is this a good approach when I don't want to spend additional budget on ASA modules?

Thanks.

```
ASAisp# 
ASAisp# show run
ASA Version 9.2(4) 
!
hostname ASAisp
domain-name soho.com

xlate per-session deny tcp any4 any4
xlate per-session deny tcp any4 any6
xlate per-session deny tcp any6 any4
xlate per-session deny tcp any6 any6
xlate per-session deny udp any4 any4 eq domain
xlate per-session deny udp any4 any6 eq domain
xlate per-session deny udp any6 any4 eq domain
xlate per-session deny udp any6 any6 eq domain
passwd .jaY8R6W./JP9tz1 encrypted
names
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/1
!             
interface Ethernet0/2
!
interface Ethernet0/3
!
interface Ethernet0/4
!
interface Ethernet0/5
!
interface Ethernet0/6
!
interface Ethernet0/7
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 172.16.0.1 255.255.0.0 
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address dhcp 
!
boot system disk0:/asa924-k8.bin
ftp mode passive
clock timezone PST -8
clock summer-time PDT recurring
dns domain-lookup inside
dns server-group DefaultDNS
 name-server 84.200.69.80
 name-server 8.8.8.8
 domain-name soho.com
same-security-traffic permit inter-interface
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface
access-list inside_access_in extended permit ip 172.16.0.0 255.255.0.0 any4 
access-list outside_access_in extended deny ip 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 any 
access-list outside_access_in extended deny ip 172.16.0.0 255.240.0.0 any 
access-list outside_access_in extended deny ip 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0 any 
pager lines 24
logging enable
logging buffer-size 987564
logging buffered informational
logging asdm informational
mtu inside 1500
mtu outside 1500
ip verify reverse-path interface inside
ip verify reverse-path interface outside
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
asdm image disk0:/asdm-762-150.bin
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
no arp permit-nonconnected
!
nat (inside,outside) after-auto source dynamic any interface
access-group inside_access_in in interface inside
access-group outside_access_in in interface outside
router ospf 1
 router-id 5.5.5.5
 network 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0 area 0
 log-adj-changes
!
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 1.2.3.4 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL 
aaa authentication http console LOCAL 
aaa local authentication attempts max-fail 3
http server enable
http 172.16.0.0 255.255.0.0 inside
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5 esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5 esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5 esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5 esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto ca trustpool policy
no crypto isakmp nat-traversal
telnet timeout 5
ssh stricthostkeycheck
ssh 172.16.0.0 255.255.0.0 inside
ssh timeout 5
ssh version 2
ssh key-exchange group dh-group1-sha1
console timeout 0
management-access inside

dhcp-client client-id interface outside
dhcpd dns 84.200.69.80 8.8.8.8
dhcpd domain soho.com
dhcpd update dns both override 
dhcpd option 3 ip 172.16.0.1
!
dhcpd address 172.16.1.100-172.16.1.130 inside
dhcpd enable inside
!
threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics host
threat-detection statistics access-list
threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept rate-interval 30 burst-rate 400 average-rate 200
ntp server 216.228.192.69 source outside
group-policy DfltGrpPolicy attributes
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 l2tp-ipsec ssl-clientless
username sndlt password ulTKijFmUYuV.Wg5 encrypted privilege 15
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map 
  inspect ftp 
  inspect h323 h225 
  inspect h323 ras 
  inspect rsh 
  inspect rtsp 
  inspect esmtp 
  inspect sqlnet 
  inspect skinny  
  inspect sunrpc 
  inspect xdmcp 
  inspect sip  
  inspect netbios 
  inspect tftp 
  inspect ip-options 
  inspect icmp 
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context 
no call-home reporting anonymous
Cryptochecksum:a5696a05725e77f8ef546ce93ebb692d
: end
ASAisp#    
ASAisp#
```

Comment: Yes and nat could be considered to fullfill the basics. Nothing can initiate a connection from the internet to inside so inbound firewall may be redundant. Outbound firewall could add a small level of security in case clients find a way around host firewall.  But if your not using the ASA for its designed purpose why not use a simple cisco router with nat and ACLS?

Comment: ASA will eventually be switched to IPS and VPN. But for now, we need this the way now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use non-standard port # to define.

```
object-group service DM_INLINE_SERVICE_1
 service-object udp destination eq 4444 
object network openNW-udp
 nat (inside,outside) static interface service udp 4444 4444
```